# Why is this type definition illegal?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing an interpreter for a small programming language, and the AST looks something like this:

```hs
data Value a = IntVal a Int | FloatVal a Float
data Expr a = AddExpr a (Value a) (Value a) | MulExpr a (Value a) (Value a)
```

I use parameter `a` for storing the line number of each term. Some functions take terms with annotations, and some take empty terms (replacing `a` with `unit`), like this:

```hs
myFunction :: Value Int -> ...
myFunction = ...

myOtherFunction :: Value () -> ...
myOtherFunction = ...
```

However, I find this alternative a bit more clear:

```hs
type Annotated b = b Int
type Bare b = b ()
```

Then, I can rewrite the previous two functions like this:

```hs
myFunction :: Annotated Value -> ...
myFunction = ...

myOtherFunction :: Bare Value -> ...
myOtherFunction = ...
```

This works great, however I also need to define a synonym for a list type with the same characteristics:

```hs
type MyList a = [Value a]
```

Now, I want to define a function taking an annotated `MyList` like so:

```hs
myOtherOtherFunction :: Annotated MyList -> ...
myOtherOtherFunction = ...
```

However, this doesn't work. The error says `The type synonym ‘MyList’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none`. Why doesn't this work? Is there any better way to define these types? Maybe with some extension?

Comment: Type synonyms can't be used as higher-order type constructors. They have to be always fully saturated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell is by default a bit pedantic that type synonyms must always be fully applied, i.e. you can't mention `MyList` without directly applying it to a concrete type parameter, thus you can't have `Annotated MyList`. The reason for this restriction is that partially applied type synonyms could be misused to form a Turing-complete language. [Oops](https://matt.might.net/articles/c++-template-meta-programming-with-lambda-calculus/)... that would be a pain for the compiler.

That said, clearly this is a bit silly for `Annotated MyList`, which is after resolved with two simple substitutions to the perfectly unspectacular `[Value Int]`, so that *should* work, shouldn't it? And indeed it does, but you need to enable a syntactic extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LiberalTypeSynonyms #-}

myOtherOtherFunction :: Annotated MyList -> ...
myOtherOtherFunction = undefined
```